# Microsoft Forms Array to Email To list

Tags: power-automate, microsoft-forms

Is there a way to get a list of options in microsoft Forms into a "to" field in a Microsoft automate email. Currently it stores everything as an array, but I need to extract just the email addresses.

Thanks

Comment: can you attach a picture of your current output

Comment: Hi I've managed to resolve it using a  list of options to parse JSON and then apply a foreach, I'm not sure how to post a picture on here. I wasn't expecting someone to write to code for me, but explain that I need to parse the information and create a foreach on the JSON. Thanks all for your response, if there is a way I can add a picture, happy to share what I've created

Answer (score 0):

[image]Thanks everyone for your response. Below I've added the solution.

Compose = (dynamic valueName)

Parse Json on the Outputs

Apply ForEach on the body, which then addes a input on current item.

You can then perform an action on the "item"